# Problems using Matlab compiled lib in .Net (32bit app on 64bit system)

Tags: .net, matlab

I'm new to using matlab-compiled code in .net app. By default, 64 bit version of Matlab was installed, and I've compiled a lib, which also was 64bit. Then I installed 64bit MCR and tried to use the code in my program (just made a test console app) and it worked.

However, then I tried to use it in an actual application, it turned out the application is developed in 32 bit. So, I installed 32 bit Matlab, compiled the lib again, to get a 32bit dll, but it doesn't work. When I try to create a class, I get this:

```
The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception.
{"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}
```

From what I get, it's because I'm using 64bit lib in 32 bit program. Which I am most assuredly not! I downloaded a program that checks wether a dll is 32 or 64 and it tells me my lib is 32 bit.

I thought this might be MCR issue and installed 32bit MCR. It still does not work. The same exception happens.

Maybe it's trying to use 64bit MCR even though 32bit MCR is installed? How can I make sure it's using the correct one?

Or is this problem a different one?