# Strange Visual Studio 2012 behavior when using 32bit dll on 64bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a 32bit dll (compiled in Matlab for .Net, so it's a .Net dll). I am on a 64bit machine, only 32bit MCR (Matlab compiler runtime) is installed (I actually had both, but uninstalled them both and reinstalled only 32 bit version to be sure that 64 bit version is not interfering somehow).

I have a solution I'm working on that has many Class Library projects and one Windows Appication project - the main executable. It was set to "Any CPU" with "Prefer 32 bit" checked, as are all the libs "Any CPU" (32 bit check is unavailable for them).

I tried to use the dll in one of the Class Libraries and encountered a problem that I explained here [Problems using Matlab compiled lib in .Net (32bit app on 64bit system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176140/problems-using-matlab-compiled-lib-in-net-32bit-app-on-64bit-system) (the error message that happens when I try to call constructor of a class from the dll is "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)").

Now, thiking this may be related to "Any CPU" setting, I've changed the "Target Platform" for the Class Library project that uses the dll and for the Windows Application project to "x86". It didn't help. The error persists!

So, here I have a solution that consists of ~20 Class Libraries (all set to Any CPU), my Class Library that uses the dll (set to x86) and Windows Application (set to x86). When I try to debug my application, it throws an exception.

Now I have made a new test solution in Visual Studio 2012, using .Net 4.5 , that consists of 2 projects: a Windows Application and a Class Library. I've added the usage of the dll to the Class Library, and set both target platforms to x86, and IT WORKS! No exception.

I checked the Output page and they're both loading the same dlls - my dll (exact copy) and MWArray dll (from exact same spot in GAC_32). And exactly same method is called (constructor from my dll).

Now, my question is, why does it work in my test solution, but not in the other solution? What can be different? From what I inspected in project properties, they are identical! Both applications are 32 bit, their Class Library DLLs are 32 bit (I double-checked that with Exe64bitDetector app).

And, here is the wierdest part:

Above I was talking about debugging. Meaning - pressing F5 or clicking Start Debug.

If I actually manually run the program from the disk (from \bin\Debug folder), it works all right! There will be no exception. However, if I use "run without debugging" option, it will still throw an exception!

I double checked the fact that there is no exception by making code like this:

```
        try
        {
            MyClassInstance = new MyClass();
            System.IO.File.Create("APPLICATION.HAS.NOT.FAILED.LOL");
        }
        catch
        {
            System.IO.File.Create("APPLICATION.FAILED.LOL");
        }
```

Then I check which file appears in the bin\Debug folder.

That is talking about the main solution of course, in the test solution either of three options work fine without exception.

What is this? I am seriously out of ideas as are all my colleagues. What can be happening here? Where do I look in order to try to solve this mystery?